# Controller method not found after adding an extra parameter

Tags: laravel-5

I have declared implicit route like below:

```
Route::controller("api/public/rental/models", 'Api\Rental\ModelsController');

public function getFees(Request $requ, $pick_up_location, $drop_off_location, $start_datetime, $end_datetime,$type)
    {
    }
```

It is working fine. But if I add any extra parameter further like below

```
public function getFees(Request $requ, $pick_up_location, $drop_off_location, $start_datetime, $end_datetime,$type,$class)
    {
    }
```

I am getting following error:

> NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 269: Controller method
>   not found.

Is there any limitation? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: can you give the path you're accessing?